# Проблема с шаблонами Django

Tags: django

Хочу переопределить письмо, которое приходит при сбросе пароля, нашёл в исходнике django файл password_reset_email.html, скопировал, вставил в свой проект (templates/registration/password_reset_email.html), в url'ах указал, чтобы использовался этот шаблон

```
path('password_reset/',
         authViews.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="mainApp/password_reset_form.html",
                                             html_email_template_name='email/password_reset_email.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
```

но теперь вылезает такая ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**password_reset_email.htm**

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktranslate %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktranslate %}

{% translate "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% translate 'Your username, in case you’ve forgotten:' %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% translate "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktranslate %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktranslate %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

В шаблоне ничего не менял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас Django 3.0.8, а судя по [документации (версия 3.1)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) тэги `translate` и `blocktranslate` ввели только в 3.1 (рамочка "Changed in Django 3.1").

Поменяйте на `trans` и `blocktrans`? В [документации на версию 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) используются как раз только они.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало)